# Heroku React + Vite Error R10 (Boot timeout)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, vite

I am trying to deploy a react + vite app on heroku. This is my Procfile
`web: npm run preview --port $PORT`. But after building on heroku it is showing these logs

```
2023-09-16T10:14:09.352404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2023-09-16T10:14:09.372574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2023-09-16T10:14:09.547280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2023-09-16T10:14:09.582055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I tried everything on google but nothing helps. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add serve
```

Now add the start script with the serve command to your script.

```
{
   //other scripts
   "start": "serve dist"
}
```

dist is the folder that your projects is built into.